# Reading signal from GNU Radio UDP sink from client side

Tags: python, gnuradio, usrp

To be honest I am a bit confused and I guess the error is quite obvious. Anyway.

So, on one side I have a UDP sink from GNU Radio sending data to a Python client.

The problem is the data I am receiving does not make much sense (I am able to properly read the data if, instead I read it from a file sink, so it has to do with the way I am doing the network part).

I tried already as little endian and also big endian, just in case, I still get rubbish.

So, on the sink side (the server side) the block config is:

```
self.blocks_udp_sink_0 = blocks.udp_sink(gr.sizeof_gr_complex*1, "the_ip",8080,1472,True)
```

So, on the other side I will get 1500 bytes, no? 1472 of payload +28 of the UDP header.

What I did, and based on this[1] example seems ok, is reading 1500 bytes in the client side and assume the header is taken out by recvfrom method:

```
data_tmp, addr = sock.recvfrom(1500)
```

I assume data_tmp shall be the 1472 bytes of data, at least the length matches).

As I am sending gr_complex I read 8 bytes (two floats little endian, one for I and one for Q components).

So, what am I missing?

Thanks!!

[1] There are many other like this one, the point is I assume the method splits the header from the payload. https://www.binarytides.com/programming-udp-sockets-in-python/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you read from a socket, the UDP header is already removed, so you shouldn't try to read 1500 bytes but 1472.

Other than that, this looks fine.

I'd generally recommend *not* using UDP (you'll have to deal with packet loss, potentially even L2 fragmentation etc yourself), but one of the ZeroMQ sinks (PUSH Socket would be a good idea here) and your favourite Python ZeroMQ library (pyzmq) as other end (PULL socket); you get low-overhead data passing interface over TCP (if you need to go over network), IPC (if your GNU Radio flow graph and the receiving program can use Unix inter-process communication) or a couple "specialist" transports.

Comment: You were absolutely right, the bug was in another part of the code. Now it works.
I will look into the other points for improvement, as I thought that basing on TCP a communication that requires this level of real time "speed" was bad practice, but I will look into the ZeroMQ point, thanks!

Comment: it does come with a penalty, indeed, but then again, you might not actually be willing to accept unnoticed packet loss.